# Not satisfied with the "correct" approach to the question, so modified it to (relatively) more realistic conditions and want to verify the answer.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A real estate man has eight master keys to open several new homes.
> Only one master key will open any given house. If 40% of these homes
> are usually left unlocked, what is the probability that the real
> estate man can get into a specific home if he selects three master
> keys at random before leaving the office?

Although I was able to solve this, however I wasn't satisfied with the "correct" approach to this question, which is to assume that the remaining 7 keys don't work at all and the only way it can be opened is to be carrying the master key to the locked house.

So my more "realistic" modification to the question was to make each of those 7 keys open $\frac{1}{7}^{th}$ of his houses. That made more sense to me (so all in all, we have one master key which unlocks every house and the remaining 7 keys which each open $\frac{1}{7}^{th}$ of the total houses). However, this has caused another partition to arise in the question (the first one being unlocked and locked houses). So, this is how I approached it :

E = unlocking

A = Unlocked house

B = Locked house

$P(E) = P(E|A)*P(A) + P(E|B)*P(B) = \frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{5}\times P(E|B) $

Since, there are 4 cases of taking the keys i.e. I = Picking up both master and the relevant key, J = Picking up only the master key, K = Picking up the relevant key & L = Picking up neither. Therefore, $P(E|B)$ :

$= P(E|I)\times P(I) + P(E|J)\times P(J) + P(E|K)\times P(K) + P(E|L)\times P(L)$

$= 1\cdot\frac{^6C_1}{^8C_3} + 2 \times ( 1\cdot\frac{^6C_2}{^8C_3} ) + 0\cdot\frac{^6C_3}{^8C_3}$

$=\frac{9}{14}$

Therefore, $P(E)= \frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{5}\times \frac{9}{14} = \frac{11}{14}$ i.e. 78.57 % chance of him having unlocked any of the houses. Is the answer correct (I am not sure of the answer because I think I might've messed up because of the new partition.)

Comment: Your intermediate result 9/14 is wrong.  We have 7 keys. We split these 7 keys in 2 groups, one with 3 keys (the winning group) and the other group with 4 keys. What is the probability for a specific key to be in the winning-group ?

Comment: For any particular house, we have 2 keys which can be used - the master and one of the seven. The real estate guy can take any 3 of those whenever he's leaving, in $^8C_3$ ways, and those 4 subdivisions I made, will add up to  $^8C_3$, making it a new partition for the question. Now, coming to your question, I think adding up 3 of those 4 subdivisions make up the wining group that unlock any of the houses, which come up to  $^8C_3 - ^6C_3$ = 36 ways out of possibly 56 ways.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see there was a master-key ! So your result 9/14 was correct. To obtain 9/14, I prefer count the probability of not having a good key. I take one 1rst key, the probability to have a wrong key is 6/8. I take a 2nd key, probability to have another wrong key is 5/7, and I take a 3rd key, proba to have another wrong key is 4/6. Proba of 3 wrong keys is (6/8)*(5/7)*(4/6)=5/14. So proba to have at least a good key is 1-5/14=9/14.